# some @media rules not adhering

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Trying to make my nonawesome website at least be mobile-friendly, I've run into a strange @media problem I can't seem to resolve.

At greater than 800px widths, the height of a my `homebutton` link back to the homepage has a `margin-top: 40vh` and it works fine. I added a media rule to the CSS to accommodate narrow width users and mobile browsers, including

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
    h1#homebutton {
        margin-top: 0;
        text-size: 1em;
    }
}
```

among other @media rules. All of the other rules on the page seem to get followed without a problem, but the `margin-top` and `text-size` rules for `h1#homebutton` will not adhere.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the answer juuuust as I was double- and triple-checking things prior to posting. Putting the question and answer here for the benefit of others similarly frustrated.

It turns out that the order of the CSS mattered; when the @media rule was *below* (i.e. lower in the code) the CSS rules it was modifying, it behaved correctly and modified them. When the @media rule was *above* the CSS it modified, the vanilla CSS beneath the rules adhered instead.

Now my @media rules are at the bottom of the CSS and it works fine.

Comment: Yes, the order of the cascade still applies, AND the specificity. So you have to make sure the earlier "vanilla" rules are not more specific than the later @media rules.